# Use of 'follows' in "Theology and histories of religion followed the Gospels." (Chekhov)

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, verbs

Excerpted from [an English translation](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/Bet.shtml) of the story "The Bet" by Anton Chekhov:

> Then after the tenth year, the prisoner sat immovably at the table and read nothing but the Gospel. It seemed strange to the banker that a man who in four years had mastered six hundred learned volumes should waste nearly a year over one thin book easy of comprehension. **Theology and histories of religion followed the Gospels.**

B is preceded by A = B follows A.

Having taken into account the explanations above, and if they are correct, would you tell me how the bold part could be correct?

Answer (score 4):

> Theology and histories of religion followed the Gospels.

This simply means that after the prisoner spent a year reading the gospels, he moved on to reading books about theology and the history of religion. He had read other books *before* he started on the Gospels - "six hundred learned volumes", but what followed his reading of the Gospel was books on religion specifically.

> B is preceded by A = B follows A.

This is correct. Books on theology were preceded by the Gospel; books on theology followed the Gospel; books on theology were read *after* reading the Gospel  - all have the same meaning.

You must be careful to distinguish "is/was preceded by" and just "preceded". All the following mean that the Gospel came first in the reading order:

> The Gospel preceded the books on theology.
>   The books on theology were preceded by the Gospel.
>   Books on theology followed the Gospel.
>   The gospel was followed by books on theology.